# Unable to upload root certificate Event Grid Namespace

Tags: azure, client-certificates, azure-eventgrid, root-certificate

I followed the documentation and generated root and intermediate certificates.
[image]

Link to documentation ->https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/mqtt-certificate-chain-client-authentication
[image]

However, Now i am unable to upload this to the event grid namespace.
[image]
How do i resolve this issue ?

Comment: the certification type should be .cer or .pem

Comment: @Sampath How do i convert it? And what type is it currently ?

Comment: can you give reference MSDOc you gone through

Comment: @Sampath https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/mqtt-certificate-chain-client-authentication

Comment: $cerPath = "C:\Path\to\Export\YourCertificateName.cer"
Export-Certificate -Cert $cert -FilePath $cerPath -Type CERT

Comment: Refer to this for [CA certificate chain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/mqtt-client-authentication).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To convert a certificate:**

```
 $certFilePath = "C:\Path\to\certificate.cer"
 Export-Certificate -Cert $cert -FilePath $certFilePath -Type CERT
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

. Refer to this for [CA certificate chain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/mqtt-client-authentication).

Answer (score 0):

The files are currently in .crt format. It has to be converted to .pem or .cer. If you can open the file in a text editor, copy the contents and save it with .pem extension to convert it to .pem.